# How can I iterate through elements of an array in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration

In Bash, if I wanted to iterate through elements of an array in a given order, I could do so like this:

```bash
for i in 1 3 8 2 5 9; do
    array[i] = <some_algorithm_based_value>
done
```

Is it possible to do the same (or relatively the same) thing in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write

```
for (int i: Arrays.asList(1, 3, 8, 2, 5, 9)) {
    doSomethingWith(array[i]);
}
```

ADDENDUM: [Live demo](http://ideone.com/af7HsF)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
  int[] arr= new int[]{1, 3, 8, 2, 5, 9};
    for(int i:arr){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Out put

```
1
3
8
2
5
9
```

Live demo [here](http://ideone.com/CNk1rV)

*FYI:* This should work only in jdk 1.7, since early version of jdk can't have a primitive type for each.

So If you are using early version of java. you have to convert `int[]` to `Integer[]` 
You can try this

```
  int[] arr= new int[]{1, 3, 8, 2, 5, 9};
    Integer[] str=new Integer[arr.length];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        str[i]=arr[i];
    }
    for(Integer i:arr){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Out put

```
1
3
8
2
5
9
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it this way

```
    for (int i : new Integer[]{1, 3, 8, 2, 5, 9}) {
        // do something
    }
```

Comment: `new int[]` would be better than `new Integer[]`, since it avoids boxing and unboxing each element between `Integer` objects and `int` primitives.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Integer integer : Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }


}
```

This will print out:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is a simple mapping from one set of values to the result of applying a function to each value, a [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)-based approach would work:

```java
int[] array = IntStream.of(1, 3, 8, 2, 5, 9).map(i -> algorithm(i)).toArray();
```